# How to convert the unity standard assets first person controller to rigidbody?

Tags: assets, character, rigidbody

I'm using the standard assets first person controller but I just realised I need the rigidbody controller instead. I don't want to switch them out though because I've made a whole bunch of customizations to the first person controller script and I don't want to redo all of them. Is there an easy way to convert it into a proper rigidbody character?

Comment: What do you mean by RigidBody Controller?  The RigidBody Component?  I don't understand your question, why can you not use the First Person Controller script alongside a RigidBody?

Comment: In my experience, if you realize you've been going in the wrong direction, it's more efficient in the long run to _go back and start again correctly_ than to _find a path from where you are to where you want to go_. Don't throw good money over bad.

Comment: @Jon http://imgur.com/plUlviy

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I'll think about it, if someone has a solution I'll give it a try otherwise thats what I'll do